# Tensorflow - Using tf.summary with 1.2 Estimator API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to add some TensorBoard logging to a model which uses the new tf.estimator API.

I have a hook set up like so:

```
summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
    save_secs=2,
    output_dir=MODEL_DIR,
    summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all())

# ...

classifier.train(
    input_fn,
    steps=1000,
    hooks=[summary_hook])
```

In my `model_fn`, I am also creating a `summary` -

```
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    # ... model stuff, calculate the value of loss
    tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
    # ...
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error from the `summary_hook`:
`Exactly one of scaffold or summary_op must be provided.` This is probably because `tf.summary.merge_all()` is not finding any summaries and is returning `None`, despite the `tf.summary.scalar` I declared in the `model_fn`.

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for whoever have this question in the future, the selected solution doesn't work for me (see my comments in the selected solution).

Actually, with TF 1.2 Estimator API, one doesn't need to have summary_hook.  I just have `tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)` in the model_fn, and run the code without summary_hook. The loss is recorded and shown in the tensorboard. I'm not sure if TF API was changed after this and similar questions.

Comment: The Estimator API does automatically handle summaries during training. But I'd like to see the same summaries during evaluation, which doesn't happen.

Comment: It works as long as you put he summaries in the `model_fn`. What if you want to summarize something in the `input_fn`? (e.g., checking the data augmentation by logging images)

Answer (score 8):

Use `tf.train.Scaffold()` and pass `tf.merge_all` as following

```
summary_hook = tf.train.SummarySaverHook(
    save_secs=2,
    output_dir=MODEL_DIR,
    scaffold=tf.train.Scaffold(summary_op=tf.summary.merge_all()))
```

Comment: I have almost the same code structure, but I get the following error: "TypeError: Fetch argument <tensorflow.python.training.monitored_session.Scaffold object at 0x5ca6310> has invalid type <class 'tensorflow.python.training.monitored_session.Scaffold'>, must be a string or Tensor. (Can not convert a Scaffold into a Tensor or Operation.)" Any idea why it's not working? Thanks!

Comment: In the new versions of Tensorflow, this works if you pass the hook to `evaluate`, but not for `train`. For train you only need to define the summaries in `mode_fn` and they will be automatically logged to tensorboard. (Yes, I also feel this is dumb and counterintuitive)

Answer (score 1):

with Tensorflow ver-r1.3

Add your summary ops in your estimator `model_fn`

example :

```
tf.summary.histogram(tensorOp.name, tensorOp)
```

If you feel writing summaries may consume time and space, you can control the writing frequency of summaries, in your Estimator `run_config`

```
run_config = tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig()
run_config = run_config.replace(model_dir=FLAGS.model_dir)
run_config = run_config.replace(save_summary_steps=150)
```

**Note: this will affect the overall summary writer frequency for TensorBoard logging, of your estimator ([tf.estimator.Estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator))**