# Tensorflow: Save metrics every certain steps

Tags: tensorflow, hook, metrics

I have trained a model and want to access the standard metrics plus a custom metric, every 100 steps.

```
def top3error(features, labels, predictions):
    return {'top3error': tf.metrics.mean(tf.nn.in_top_k(predictions=predictions['logits'], 
                                                        targets=labels,
                                                        k=3))}
m = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(
      # Config & Params
      config=config
      model_dir=model_dir,
      n_classes=n_classes,
      # Model
      feature_columns=deep_columns,
      hidden_units=[256, 128],
      activation_fn='relu',
      optimizer=tf.train.ProximalAdagradOptimizer(
        learning_rate=0.1,
        l1_regularization_strength=0.001)
    )
'''Add metrics'''          
m = tf.estimator.add_metrics(m, top3error)
```

I have added a config variable to specify that every 100 steps I want to save the metrics. I have been successful to print the metrics.

```
config=tf.estimator.RunConfig(
  model_dir=model_dir, 
  save_checkpoints_steps=100,
)
```

However after the model has been trained I can only access the last value for each metric. Is it possible to save the metrics everytime there is a checkpoint?

```
  results = tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(m, train_spec, eval_spec)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use tensorflow summaries. You can also use that to visualize your metric in tensorboard.

check this out->[Tensorflow Estimator API: Summaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164772/tensorflow-estimator-api-summaries)